# Not able to send Cloud to Device Message to Azure IoT hub

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

So, I am trying to send the messages to Azure IoT Hub usind Python. I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-c2d) document but when I run the script:

```py
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager

RECEIVED_MESSAGES = 0

CONNECTION_STRING = "<IoT Hub Connection String>"
DEVICE_ID = "<IoT Edge Device ID>"

def iothub_messaging_sample_run():
    
    # Create IoTHubRegistryManager
    registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
    i = 0

    while True:
        i += 1
        print(f'Sending message: {i}')
        data = f'NodeId : Node{i}, Message : Message{i}'
        registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting the Python IoT Hub C2D Messaging service sample...')

    iothub_messaging_sample_run()
```

It first prints this:
`Sending message: 1`
And then throws this error:
`Exception: C2D message send failure`
The rest of the error logs doesn't contain any additional information, just the references to the Azure IoT Hub Package Files.

I have already enabled `Inbound Port 8883` on Firewall but still I am not able to send data to Azure IoT Hub.

Configurations:

- Python Version - 3.7.3
- Packages - azure-iot-hub==2.6.0
- OS - Windows 10 Home
- IoT Hub - Standard Tier S1
- Azure Subscription - Azure for Students
- Number of IoT Hub Units - 1
- IoT Hub Location - East US
- Minimum TLS Version - 1.0
- Number of Devices - 1 (IoT Edge Device)

Answer (score 0):

Working through the tutorial linked I noticed that your implementation is quite different. Still, when I copy your code, it does work on my machine, but there are two reasons that I know of that can result in this error:

1. You entered the wrong device ID.
2. The C2D queue of the device is full. There is a 50 messages limit on C2D message queues. Make sure your device (or the device Python file in the tutorial) is listening to empty the queue. Your code has no delays in it, so you're filling up the queue within seconds, the next time you start the program, it might crash at the first message.

I also noted you wrote:

```py
DEVICE_ID = "<IoT Edge Device ID>"
```

Azure IoT Edge devices don't support C2D messages, it won't result in an error though, but you will not be able to receive the messages on the device.

Comment: So this process can't be performed on Azure IoT Devices and rather simple Devices in my IoT hub ?

Comment: The opposite, it can only be performed on Azure IoT Devices. Just not [Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11) devices.